# Failing to pass onClick function to different file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, state, react-props

So I have two .js files (are they also called modules?). The first .js file is a class-based component. It has `handleClick()` as well as `render()`. It looks like this (I've actually removed a lot of the code to make it appear shorter here):

```
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('handleclick')
    this.initializeFetchApiAndSetState()
}

//Helper Function
checkGuessForCorrectAnswer() {
    console.log('correct answer!')
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-main">

            <MultipleChoices
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                data={this.state.guess1}
            />

            <button 
                className='Submit' 
                onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
                Submit
            </button>

        </div>
    )
}
```

The button above works fine in that I can click on it and it'll console log the word 'correct answer!'. But for some reason, when I try to pass onClick to the "MultipleChoices" file/module it doesn't console log 'correct answer!'. The MultipleChoices.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react"

function MultipleChoices(props) {

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="button-grid">
                <button
                    className="btn"
                    value={props.data}
                    onClick={props.handleClick}
                > 
                    {props.data}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MultipleChoices
```

Why can the button activate onClick in the first file, but not when I try to pass onClick to the MultipleChoice.js (which also has a button)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your upper component, you need to replace the `onClick` property with a `handleClick` property.

```
<MultipleChoices
  handleClick={this.handleClick}
  data={this.state.guess1}
/>
```

Because inside the Multiple Choices component you are calling the handleClick method from the properties (which is not set)

Answer (score 2):

In your parent component you have given name to your property as onClick, while you are trying to acces it in children component as prop.handleClick.